# mongodb detect change in value and get the first and last record from its range

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Consider the following dataset in mongodb.

[image]

When the count restarts, reset flag is set to true. I need to get the start and end time of the range of records between two resets. In this example, the last record is set to false, to indicate there are more records to come. I need to get this last record as well.

Note that the data is on mongodb.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.